# DataSync issue from FrontEnd

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-sync

We are using azure data sync to sync data from one database to another. We have created a new sync group for another environment. **we don't have any issues from backend as sync is running fine** but we are having below DataSync error from Frontend side when user try functionality that is related to table participating in DataSync.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'local_create_peer_timestamp', table** 'PULSECOACHIN_7_QCEC.DataSync.CoachingSessionNotificationScheduler_dss_tracking'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Comment: The error message is very clearly,  it has the null value, please recheck the value.

Comment: By chance, Is that a computed column?

Comment: We are are not inserting any data to those Columns or tables .those are DataSync tables which are automatically created by when the sync is enabled.